After upgrade to Couchbase.Lite 3.2.0 .NET windows application installing is failed
In our .NET windows application, We recently upgraded Couchbase.Lite to 3.2.0 but we got an error at
CouchDatabase = new Database(“xxxxx”);

Researched on this and found that it’s because of target platform x86. this version will only work in x64 target platform of widows application. So changed target platform of windows app to x64 and able to run successfully in local.
But we got an issue in installation. So we changed setup project target platform to x64 and we are adding three primary outputs to setup project. one windows application and two windows services because when ever we are installing this application, it will install windows app and two windows services in background. So we changed windows services target platform to x64 as well able to build setup project successfully after newly added things which are build under x64.
But still we are facing below issue

We researched on it and what we understand is there are some dependencies may left which are from x86 but we rebuild under x64 and newly added.
Are we missing anything in this process? Please suggest a solution for this?
Thanks in advance
Venkatrao
